# Confused about SVD, why does it not imply all matricies are diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

For SVD decomposition, if $X = U \Sigma V^T$. Then for

$$XX^T=U\Sigma V^T V\Sigma U^T=U \Sigma I \Sigma U^T = U \Sigma^2 U^T = \Sigma^2 \ ?$$
I believe $U$ and $V$ are both orthonormal matrices so this should work. But could someone help point out the error I have made?

As it's definitely not true that all matrices are diagonals.

Comment: Matrices do not commute, your last equality is false. And $XX^T$ is always symmetric, so this would not cover "all matrices" even if it did work.

Comment: SVD implies all matrixes of the form $XX^T$ are similar to a diagonal matrix. But as they are always symmetric, this is already known.